# SASS how can I add a class to a tag using the ampersand?

Tags: sass

How can I write these sass declarations so that it compiles to `a.btn_primary_cancel`

I tried this but it's not working:

```
.btn_primary_cancel {

  a& {
    line-height: 4rem;
  }

}
```

Comment: check this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42917110/4947434

Answer (score 3):

> Yes !! You can have the desired result. Just use `@at-root`

Try this code.

```
.btn_primary_cancel {
  @at-root a#{&} {
    line-height: 4rem;
  }
}
```

it will compile to

```
a.btn_primary_cancel {
  line-height: 4rem;
}
```

See this in action -  [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/jinukurian7/pen/XMZyYB)

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
a {
  &.btn_primary_cancel {
    line-height: 4rem;
  }
}
```

Which will compile to:

```
a.btn_primary_cancel {
  line-height: 4rem;
}
```

Comment: I want to keep everything under .btn_primary_cancel. The same class is used for button tags and a tags and I just need specific styling on the a tags.

Comment: then use the same code but put: a, button { &.btn_primary_cancel... }

Comment: No, that would create an a.btn_primary_cancel and a button.btn_primary_cancel declaration

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the ampersand in #{&} will work, but not as you think.

Because it is **within** the class declaration, it will create the following:

```
.btn_primary_cancel {
  a#{&} {
    line-height: 4rem;
  }
}
```

Outputs to:

```
.btn_primary_cancel a.btn_primary_cancel {
  line-height: 4rem;
}
```

This said, I don't think you can do what you are requesting. The CSS hierarchy simply doesn't work that way.